# What is the maximum number of results for people.searchContacts?

Tags: google-people-api

The `PeopleAPI` reference says how many is the maximum number of `people.searchContacts`?

There is a parameter in `people.searchContacts` that specifies the PageSize, and the possible range for this is 0-100 (if this is exceeded, the API will return an error with code 400).

In fact, the maximum number of contacts returned in my environment is 10.

When I call the API, I am doing so from the PeopleAPI reference.
I have contacts with only names from "test001" to "test692".

I made the following call.

```
pageSize=100 
query=test 
readMask=names
```

In fact, the search is successful because 10 results are returned.
The actual API response is as follows.
Obviously, the object PERSON is only 10.

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "person": {
        "resourceName": "people/c8168479585467794596",
        "etag": "%EgUBAj03LhoBAiIMNnpSRkhHZGx0MWc9",
        "names": [
          {
            "metadata": {
              "primary": true,
              "source": {
                "type": "CONTACT",
                "id": "715c44e78ed684a4"
              }
            },
            "displayName": "test344",
            "givenName": "test344",
            "displayNameLastFirst": "test344",
            "unstructuredName": "test344"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "person": {
        "resourceName": "people/c3167515375063584231",
        "etag": "%EgUBAj03LhoBAiIMYXNYSDFwK2F5M2s9",
        "names": [
          {
            "metadata": {
              "primary": true,
              "source": {
                "type": "CONTACT",
                "id": "2bf546738f40cde7"
              }
            },
            "displayName": "test475",
            "givenName": "test475",
            "displayNameLastFirst": "test475",
            "unstructuredName": "test475"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "person": {
        "resourceName": "people/c3282072175076995161",
        "etag": "%EgUBAj03LhoBAiIMNnpSRkhHZGx0MWc9",
        "names": [
          {
            "metadata": {
              "primary": true,
              "source": {
                "type": "CONTACT",
                "id": "2d8c43410aa87059"
              }
            },
            "displayName": "test324",
            "givenName": "test324",
            "displayNameLastFirst": "test324",
            "unstructuredName": "test324"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "person": {
        "resourceName": "people/c93297420873589595",
        "etag": "%EgUBAj03LhoBAiIMNnpSRkhHZGx0MWc9",
        "names": [
          {
            "metadata": {
              "primary": true,
              "source": {
                "type": "CONTACT",
                "id": "14b75828da1635b"
              }
            },
            "displayName": "test375",
            "givenName": "test375",
            "displayNameLastFirst": "test375",
            "unstructuredName": "test375"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "person": {
        "resourceName": "people/c7551199169689611221",
        "etag": "%EgUBAj03LhoBAiIMYXNYSDFwK2F5M2s9",
        "names": [
          {
            "metadata": {
              "primary": true,
              "source": {
                "type": "CONTACT",
                "id": "68cb3fa30992ebd5"
              }
            },
            "displayName": "test410",
            "givenName": "test410",
            "displayNameLastFirst": "test410",
            "unstructuredName": "test410"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "person": {
        "resourceName": "people/c1565155306977622025",
        "etag": "%EgUBAj03LhoBAiIMYXNYSDFwK2F5M2s9",
        "names": [
          {
            "metadata": {
              "primary": true,
              "source": {
                "type": "CONTACT",
                "id": "15b88c758ab7f809"
              }
            },
            "displayName": "test502",
            "givenName": "test502",
            "displayNameLastFirst": "test502",
            "unstructuredName": "test502"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "person": {
        "resourceName": "people/c5338499009621013269",
        "etag": "%EgUBAj03LhoBAiIMOG5lYXFOY2dSMEk9",
        "names": [
          {
            "metadata": {
              "primary": true,
              "source": {
                "type": "CONTACT",
                "id": "4a1628908e3c3315"
              }
            },
            "displayName": "test045",
            "givenName": "test045",
            "displayNameLastFirst": "test045",
            "unstructuredName": "test045"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "person": {
        "resourceName": "people/c1634993899755826693",
        "etag": "%EgUBAj03LhoBAiIMeFhRTGVVTUpwV1U9",
        "names": [
          {
            "metadata": {
              "primary": true,
              "source": {
                "type": "CONTACT",
                "id": "16b0aa4a0ce06e05"
              }
            },
            "displayName": "test682",
            "givenName": "test682",
            "displayNameLastFirst": "test682",
            "unstructuredName": "test682"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "person": {
        "resourceName": "people/c2147830404560755472",
        "etag": "%EgUBAj03LhoBAiIMYXNYSDFwK2F5M2s9",
        "names": [
          {
            "metadata": {
              "primary": true,
              "source": {
                "type": "CONTACT",
                "id": "1dcea05f8da09b10"
              }
            },
            "displayName": "test412",
            "givenName": "test412",
            "displayNameLastFirst": "test412",
            "unstructuredName": "test412"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "person": {
        "resourceName": "people/c1471134701871216797",
        "etag": "%EgUBAj03LhoBAiIMNnpSRkhHZGx0MWc9",
        "names": [
          {
            "metadata": {
              "primary": true,
              "source": {
                "type": "CONTACT",
                "id": "146a853789c8b89d"
              }
            },
            "displayName": "test257",
            "givenName": "test257",
            "displayNameLastFirst": "test257",
            "unstructuredName": "test257"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The groups to be searched are as follows

```
{
  "resourceName": "contactGroups/70239db70d7a542c",
  "etag": "oa89KnGjASc=",
  "metadata": {
    "updateTime": "2021-04-13T03:38:14.374Z"
  },
  "groupType": "USER_CONTACT_GROUP",
  "name": "インポート: 4/13",
  "formattedName": "インポート: 4/13",
  "memberCount": 691
}
```

Comment: Can you confirm that the query performed does indeed return more than 10 results? Moreover, can you share the call you are making as well with the structure of the response you are receiving?

Comment: Thank you, ale13.
I followed your words and checked the response of the API you called.
However, the result of this is never more than 10 (even though it should obviously return more than 100).

Comment: When I call the API, I am doing so from the PeopleAPI reference.
I have contacts with only names from "test001" to "test692".

I made the following call.

pageSize=100
query=test
readMask=names

In fact, the search is successful because 10 results are returned.

Comment: {
  "results": [
    {
      "person": {
        "resourceName": "people/c8168479585467794596",
        "etag": "%EgUBAj03LhoBAiIMNnpSRkhHZGx0MWc9",
        "names": [
          {
            "metadata": {
              "primary": true,
              "source": {
                "type": "CONTACT",
                "id": "715c44e78ed684a4"
              }
            },
            "displayName": "test344",
            "givenName": "test344",
            "displayNameLastFirst": "test344",
            "unstructuredName": "test344"
          }
        ]
      }
  },

Comment: The [method description](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/searchContacts) specifies: "Provides a list of contacts in the authenticated user's `grouped contacts`". Are the contacts you created in a group? Double-check by retrieving the group with [contactGroups.get](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/contactGroups/get) - the response will contain `memberCount`. Also, doublecheck from the [UI](https://contacts.google.com/) that the number of your contacts matches your expectations.

Comment: Thanks, ziganotschka.
The contacts from test001 to test692, created by the CSV import, fit into the labels generated during the import.
This was found from the memberCount in contactGroups.list.
The value of memberCount is 691.
The list of groups to be searched and the contacts under the groups are added above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I could reproduce your problem and can confirm that the number of returned results is capped to 10

It seems to be a bug.

I have taken the liberty of filing it for you on [Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/185357672).

I recommend you to "star" it to increase visibility.

Comment: ziganotschka, thanks!
I'll keep an eye on Google Issue Tracker!